# App crashes when trying to push view controller

Tags: swift, xcode, crash, viewcontroller

So I have the following block of code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    // Recall cell to call further cell data
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! FollowersCell

    var i: Int = 0;

    // if user tapped on himself, go home. If not, go guest 
    if cell.usernameLabel.text == PFUser.current()!.username! {
        let home = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(home, animated: true)
    } else {
        print("You made it inside the else - clause")
        print(cell.usernameLabel.text!) // this prints out the correct username no matter which user I click on
        guestName.append(cell.usernameLabel.text!)
        print(guestName[i]) // this should print out the same as cell.usernameLabel.text (I think?) but only prints out whichever user I press the first time during runtime
        print(i) // this should print 0,1,2,3,... incrementing each time I press a given user, but it always prints only 0
        i = i + 1 // incrementing i by one
        let guest = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GuestViewController") as? GuestViewController
        print("Made it this far")

        if guest == nil {
            print("The view controller is nil for some reason")
        } else {
            print("The view controller is not nil but it still doesn't work")
        }
        //self.navigationController?.pushViewController(guest!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Whenever I tap on the view that is supposed to call this function, the following is printed to the logs:

```
You made it inside the else - clause
test3
test3
0
Made it this far
The view controller is not nil but it still doesn't work
```

As you can see I've put in some checkpoints and lines to print out information about the state of my program, and I've added some comments in the code as well, please take a look at those as they explain some of the things I'm having trouble with. However it's the last line (that's commented out) that's causing me the most trouble. For some reason whenever I uncomment that line my app crashes with the following error: [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXgtz.png), and I get the following message in my logs:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Is anyone able to see what the problem is? As you can see from the code, the view controller I'm trying to push is not nil. I've been stuck on this for days and can't seem to figure it out.

EDIT
Here's GuestViewController:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

var guestName = [String]()

class GuestViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    // UI Objects 
    var refresher: UIRefreshControl!
    var page: Int = 10

    // Arrays to hold data from server
    var uuidArray = [String]()
    var pictureArray = [PFFile]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionView!.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        self.navigationItem.title = guestName.last?.uppercased()

        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(GuestViewController.back(_:)))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton

        // Swipe to go back
        let backSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GuestViewController.back(_:)))
        backSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(backSwipe)

        // Pull to refresh
        refresher = UIRefreshControl()
        refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GuestViewController.refresh), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
        collectionView?.addSubview(refresher)

        // Load posts 
        loadPosts()

    }

    func back(_ sender : UIBarButtonItem) {
        _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

        if !guestName.isEmpty {
            guestName.removeLast()
        }
    }

    func refresh() {
        collectionView?.reloadData()
        refresher.endRefreshing()
    }

    func loadPosts() {
        let query = PFQuery(className: "posts")
        query.whereKey("username", equalTo: guestName.last!)
        query.limit = page
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                for object in objects! {
                    self.uuidArray.append(object.value(forKey: "uuid") as! String)
                    self.pictureArray.append(object.value(forKey: "picture") as! PFFile)
                }
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    // Cell number
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pictureArray.count
    }

    // Cell configuration 
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! pictureCell
        pictureArray[indexPath.row].getDataInBackground { (data, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                cell.picture.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }
        }
        return cell
    }

    // header configuration 
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", for: indexPath) as! HeaderViewController


        // Load data of guest 

        let infoQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
        infoQuery.whereKey("username", equalTo: guestName.last!)
        infoQuery.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            } else {

                // shown wrong user
                if objects!.isEmpty {
                    print("Wrong user")
                }

                // find user information 
                for object in objects! {
                    header.fullnameLabel.text = (object.object(forKey: "fullname") as? String)?.uppercased()
                    header.bioLabel.text  = object.object(forKey: "bio") as? String
                    header.bioLabel.sizeToFit()
                    let profilePictureFile: PFFile = (object.object(forKey: "profilePicture") as? PFFile)!
                    profilePictureFile.getDataInBackground(block: { (data, error) in
                        header.profilePicture.image = UIImage(data: data!)

                    })
                }
            }
        }

        // Show if current user is following guest

        let followQuery = PFQuery(className: "Follow")
        followQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.current()!.username!)
        followQuery.whereKey("following", equalTo: guestName.last!)
        followQuery.countObjectsInBackground { (count, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                if count == 0 {
                    header.profileButton.setTitle("Follow", for: .normal)
                    header.bioLabel.backgroundColor = .lightGray
                } else {
                    header.profileButton.setTitle("Following", for: .normal)
                    header.profileButton.backgroundColor = .green

                }
            }
        }

        // Count statistics 

        // count posts 
        let posts = PFQuery(className: "posts")
        posts.whereKey("username", equalTo: guestName.last!)
        posts.countObjectsInBackground { (count, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                header.posts.text = "\(count)"
            }
        }

        // count followers 
        let followers = PFQuery(className: "posts")
        posts.whereKey("following", equalTo: guestName.last!)
        posts.countObjectsInBackground { (count, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                header.followers.text = "\(count)"
            }
        }

        // count followings 
        let followings = PFQuery(className: "posts")
        posts.whereKey("follower", equalTo: guestName.last!)
        followings.countObjectsInBackground { (count, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                header.following.text = "\(count)"
            }
        }

        // Implement tap gestures 

        // tap to post 
        let postsTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GuestViewController.postsTap))
        postsTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        header.posts.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        header.posts.addGestureRecognizer(postsTap)

        // tap to followers
        let followersTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GuestViewController.followersTap))
        followersTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        header.followers.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        header.followers.addGestureRecognizer(followersTap)

        // tap to followings 
        let followingsTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GuestViewController.followingsTap))
        followingsTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        header.following.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        header.following.addGestureRecognizer(followingsTap)




        return header
    }

    func postsTap() {

        if !pictureArray.isEmpty {
            let index = NSIndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
            self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: index as IndexPath, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)
        }

    }

    func followersTap() {

        user = guestName.last!
        category = "followers"
        let followers = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FollowersViewController") as! FollowersViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(followers, animated: true)
    }

    func followingsTap() {

        user = guestName.last!
        category = "followings"
        let followings = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FollowersViewController") as! FollowersViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(followings, animated: true)
    }
}
```

And here's the full logs from start to crash:

```
2017-03-13 20:28:26.093035 w2c7[14482:1381876] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2017-03-13 20:28:26.100218 w2c7[14482:1381876] [] ____nwlog_simulate_crash_inner_block_invoke dlopen CrashReporterSupport failed
2017-03-13 20:28:26.100529 w2c7[14482:1381876] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash simulate crash failed "nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available"
2017-03-13 20:28:26.101709 w2c7[14482:1381876] [] nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available, dumping backtrace:
        [x86_64] libnetcore-856.30.16
    0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x000000010ea4a666 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
    1   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4e3006 nw_socket_add_input_handler + 3164
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4c0555 nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols + 3768
    3   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4bf572 nw_endpoint_flow_setup_socket + 563
    4   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4be298 -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow startWithHandler:] + 2612
    5   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4d9ae1 nw_endpoint_handler_path_change + 1261
    6   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4d9510 nw_endpoint_handler_start + 570
    7   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4f11f9 nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child + 2240
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7c7978 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7f10cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7cee17 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 236
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7cfb4b _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1073
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7d2385 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7d2059 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010eb9a4de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010eb98341 start_wqthread + 13
2017-03-13 20:28:26.119252 w2c7[14482:1381876] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2017-03-13 20:28:26.124506 w2c7[14482:1381876] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash simulate crash already simulated "nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available"
2017-03-13 20:28:26.125618 w2c7[14482:1381876] [] nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available, dumping backtrace:
        [x86_64] libnetcore-856.30.16
    0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x000000010ea4a666 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
    1   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4e3006 nw_socket_add_input_handler + 3164
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4c0555 nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols + 3768
    3   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4bf572 nw_endpoint_flow_setup_socket + 563
    4   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4be298 -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow startWithHandler:] + 2612
    5   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4d9ae1 nw_endpoint_handler_path_change + 1261
    6   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4d9510 nw_endpoint_handler_start + 570
    7   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4f11f9 nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child + 2240
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7c7978 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7f10cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7cee17 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 236
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7cfb4b _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1073
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7d2385 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7d2059 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010eb9a4de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010eb98341 start_wqthread + 13
2017-03-13 20:28:26.127269 w2c7[14482:1381876] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2017-03-13 20:28:26.131263 w2c7[14482:1381876] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash simulate crash already simulated "nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available"
2017-03-13 20:28:26.131965 w2c7[14482:1381876] [] nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available, dumping backtrace:
        [x86_64] libnetcore-856.30.16
    0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x000000010ea4a666 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
    1   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4e3006 nw_socket_add_input_handler + 3164
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4c0555 nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols + 3768
    3   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4bf572 nw_endpoint_flow_setup_socket + 563
    4   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4be298 -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow startWithHandler:] + 2612
    5   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4d9ae1 nw_endpoint_handler_path_change + 1261
    6   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4d9510 nw_endpoint_handler_start + 570
    7   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4f11f9 nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child + 2240
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7c7978 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7f10cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7cee17 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 236
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7cfb4b _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1073
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7d2385 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7d2059 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010eb9a4de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010eb98341 start_wqthread + 13
2017-03-13 20:28:26.133267 w2c7[14482:1381876] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2017-03-13 20:28:26.136343 w2c7[14482:1381876] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash simulate crash already simulated "nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available"
2017-03-13 20:28:26.136837 w2c7[14482:1381876] [] nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available, dumping backtrace:
        [x86_64] libnetcore-856.30.16
    0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x000000010ea4a666 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
    1   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4e3006 nw_socket_add_input_handler + 3164
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4c0555 nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols + 3768
    3   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4bf572 nw_endpoint_flow_setup_socket + 563
    4   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4be298 -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow startWithHandler:] + 2612
    5   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4d9ae1 nw_endpoint_handler_path_change + 1261
    6   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4d9510 nw_endpoint_handler_start + 570
    7   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4f11f9 nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child + 2240
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7c7978 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7f10cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7cee17 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 236
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7cfb4b _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1073
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7d2385 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7d2059 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010eb9a4de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010eb98341 start_wqthread + 13
Followings loaded
2017-03-13 20:28:30.369257 w2c7[14482:1381917] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2017-03-13 20:28:30.373519 w2c7[14482:1381917] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash simulate crash already simulated "nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available"
2017-03-13 20:28:30.374350 w2c7[14482:1381917] [] nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available, dumping backtrace:
        [x86_64] libnetcore-856.30.16
    0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x000000010ea4a666 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
    1   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4e3006 nw_socket_add_input_handler + 3164
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4c0555 nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols + 3768
    3   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4bf572 nw_endpoint_flow_setup_socket + 563
    4   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4be298 -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow startWithHandler:] + 2612
    5   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4d9ae1 nw_endpoint_handler_path_change + 1261
    6   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4d9510 nw_endpoint_handler_start + 570
    7   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4f11f9 nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child + 2240
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7c7978 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7f10cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7cee17 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 236
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7cfb4b _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1073
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7d2385 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7d2059 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010eb9a4de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010eb98341 start_wqthread + 13
2017-03-13 20:28:30.993304 w2c7[14482:1381876] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
2017-03-13 20:28:30.996557 w2c7[14482:1381876] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash simulate crash already simulated "nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available"
2017-03-13 20:28:30.997102 w2c7[14482:1381876] [] nw_socket_set_common_sockopts setsockopt SO_NOAPNFALLBK failed: [42] Protocol not available, dumping backtrace:
        [x86_64] libnetcore-856.30.16
    0   libsystem_network.dylib             0x000000010ea4a666 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 123
    1   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4e3006 nw_socket_add_input_handler + 3164
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4c0555 nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols + 3768
    3   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4bf572 nw_endpoint_flow_setup_socket + 563
    4   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4be298 -[NWConcrete_nw_endpoint_flow startWithHandler:] + 2612
    5   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4d9ae1 nw_endpoint_handler_path_change + 1261
    6   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4d9510 nw_endpoint_handler_start + 570
    7   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000010f4f11f9 nw_endpoint_resolver_start_next_child + 2240
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7c7978 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7f10cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7cee17 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 236
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7cfb4b _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1073
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7d2385 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 720
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010e7d2059 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010eb9a4de _pthread_wqthread + 1129
    15  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010eb98341 start_wqthread + 13
You made it inside the else - clause
test3
test3
0
Made it this far
The view controller is not nil but it still doesn't work
```

Comment: The crash is likely caused by something in GuestViewController. But you didn't show any of that. — Also, Xcode at the time of the crash displays a lot of valuable info about what was happening at that moment, but you have cropped it all out from your screen shot.

Comment: I'm assuming your new enough to iOS development. So you may not know about this, In Xcode, on the left pane. The third icon from the right is the Debug navigator. You can step back though the process to find the line that caused your crash. You should run your app again and make it crash, then check this tab and click though the thread

Comment: I am quite new yes, although I do have a little bit of experience with the debug navigator. It doesn't offer me any useful info unfortunately, it only gives the red line in the app delegate (that I've posted in my original question) and a whole bunch of weird stuff coming from files that I don't recognize (i.e. files I haven't written myself so I assume they're files existing "inside" Xcode so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

Having passed almost a year, you sure must have solved it, but just in case, check that, if you have copied and pasted components from another VC in the Storyboard, that the outlets of those components are "unplugged" or removed in the Storyboard, for that VC

Answer (score 0):

On the actual storyboard itself that contains the GuestViewController, is the storyboard id set? Furthermore is it exactly the same as you have it set in the code, in terms of spelling/capitalization? Furthermore, for this line of code, instead of the question mark after the "as", put it to a "!".

```
let guest = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "GuestViewController") as? GuestViewController.
```

Also are you sure the GuestViewController on the storyboard, the class isn't set? Or perhaps set to the wrong class? Lastly, are you sure everything is embedded in a NavigationController?

Comment: The storyboard ID is set and it is identical to how it's set it in the code. I originally had my code as you suggest (replacing the ? with ! after as) and the problem persists unchanged. The only reason I added the ? was so that I could check if guest was nil a few lines down. Also the class is set correctly on storyboard. The only thing I'm not 100% certain of is whether or not everything is embedded in NavigationController, is there a simple way to check this? How can I identify if everything indeed is embedded in a Navigation controller?

Comment: Well you explicitly set it to be in a UInavigation Controller, so if you aren't sure then it probably isn't. What you want to do is, on the very first ViewController that the app starts on within the storyboard, click on that particular view controller, then in the top menu bar in xCode, click  "Editor", go down to "Embed in", then Navigation controller. This sets that initial ViewController to become the "RootViewController". Try this, and let me know if it works. If not let me see your code.

Comment: Very simple to test, does the app crash when you select the cell matching the currrentUsers name. If not then the issue is not the UINavigationController.

Comment: @Devster101 great point, is the delegate/datasource set for the UITableView?

Comment: The datasource and delegate would be set as the code does run when he selects the cell. This has to be an issue with the GuestViewController not being hooked up correctly. @torola have you tried placing a breakpoint on the first line of the viewDidLoad on the GuestViewController class

Comment: @Devster101 it's hard to test for if the cell is matching currentUser because the table is showing people following the current user. So I would have to go to someone else's profile and from there I could see the current user in the table, but it's a circular problem because I can't "guest" anyone else's profile to begin with. I've also tried putting a breakpoint on the first line of the viewDidLoad on the GuestViewController class but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be looking for...

Comment: @torola Does the app get to that breakpoint before it crashes?

Comment: @Devster101 yes it does.

Comment: If the code reaches the viewDidLoad then the problem exists in the GuestViewController. Did you try stepping through and seeing where the crash appears.

Comment: @Devster101 Yes, I can step through every line of the entire viewDidLoad() without errors but the moment I step past the last line of it's implementation the app crashes. So it seems that the app crashes once viewDidLoad() is done running. I just want to thank for your help so far, I feel like we're narrowing down on the problem:)

Comment: @Devster101 I should say, at the point where the app crashes while going through the breakpoints I get this error: " Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.' " After some googling it seems that this means I'm trying to do something to a PFQuery while it's in the middle of the previous operation, and that I have to check to see whether I'm making two query calls on the same query object without waiting for the first to complete. Does this tell you anything?

Comment: Then I would guess this issue lies in your viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind method where you query the "posts" class several times. Try commenting out 2 of the 3 queries and check if the crash persists.

Comment: Actually, you call another query on the posts class when you call load posts. So remove them all in viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind for now

Comment: You are an absolute godsend. When I commented out all three it FINALLY worked. I've been pulling my hair out for weeks on this, thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Try it without the exclamation point after `guest` in your call to push the view controller.   Or else put an exclamation point after `GuestViewController` in your line where you set the value of `guest`.  Doing this will declare it as an Optional(GuestViewController). That means your variable can be either a GuestViewController or it can be nil.

It is undefined to refer to `guest!` if you have not declared it as an Optional.  Also, if you have not declared it as an Optional, it is unnecessary to check to see whether it is nil.

Comment: I tried everything in your post but the problem still persists.